# Why does this react-spring animation change its margin-top during an animation?

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I have a react-spring animation that consists in make a component appear while sliding. But during this animation, the component change its margin top before going back to normal. How to fix this?

Here is the code & a sandbox:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import styled, { css, keyframes } from "styled-components";
import { animated, useTransition } from "react-spring";

const Tabs = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
`;

const Tab = styled.button<{ active: boolean }>`
  margin: 0 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  font-weight: ${({ active }) => active && 600};
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  &:focus {
    outline: none !important;
  }
`;

export default function Inbox() {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState(0);

  const transitions = useTransition(tab, (p) => p, {
    from: { opacity: 0, transform: "translate3d(100%,0,0)" },
    enter: { opacity: 1, transform: "translate3d(0%,0,0)" },
    leave: { opacity: 0, transform: "translate3d(-50%,0,0)" }
  });

  const getList = (name: string) => <div>{name}</div>;

  const pages = [
    ({ style }) => (
      <animated.div style={style}>{getList("test 1")}</animated.div>
    ),
    ({ style }) => (
      <animated.div style={style}>{getList("test 2")}</animated.div>
    )
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Tabs>
        <Tab onClick={() => setTab(0)} active={tab === 0}>
          Unread
        </Tab>
        <Tab onClick={() => setTab(1)} active={tab === 1}>
          All
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
      {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => {
        const Page = pages[item];
        return <Page key={key} style={props} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

The sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-ride-hwbv2?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the margin top you see. It is the old component moving to the left side and changing opacity, but it is still there. Finally it is unmounted in that moment the new component is taking its vertical place. Most of the time we use absolute positionig that the old and new components are on top of each other. This way there is no bump at the unmount. Something like this:

`from: { opacity: 0, transform: "translate3d(100%,0,0)", position: "absolute" },`

Comment: Thanks it works! However, React claims that it can't perform an update on an unmounted component, which means there is a memory leak in this small script. It must come from React Spring animation, because there is nothing else. Would you know how to fix this leak too?

Comment: I found an issue (https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/906). It said that a similar problem is working in version 9. I tried with a random version (9.0.0-beta.2) and it works without problem. I do not know what to recommend. Version numbers are confusing. Either you pick the highest  beta number it is works or you can use the newest rc.3 but you have to refactor your code as it use a slightly different api. Or you wait a little to the final version 9.